# Can eth_estimateGas estimate gas for past blocks?

Tags: gas, json-rpc, gas-estimate, eth-call

In my understanding, the [eth_estimateGas](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/eth_estimateGas) json rpc method can currently only be used to estimate how much gas would be needed for a transaction based on the current/latest state of the blockchain.

However, I'm curious if this is the case and it's not currently possible to estimate gas usage for past blocks using this method. This question arises especially since `eth_call` allows us to make static calls specifying a particular block, essentially letting us query the state of the blockchain at a historical block.

1. Can `eth_estimateGas` be used to estimate gas for transactions in past blocks?
2. If not, what's the rationale behind not allowing gas estimation at a specific block, especially when methods like `eth_call` support querying historical blocks?

Comment: So if the EOA i.e. "from" isn't relevant to the gas estimation you could have a contract that does the call instead of the EOA doing the call directly and have this contract calculate the gas used from the call by subtracting the `gasleft` immediately after the call from the `gasleft` immediately before the call as the [UniswapInterfaceMulticall contract does](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/lens/UniswapInterfaceMulticall.sol)